# If every ideal not contained in Nil(A) has an idempotent, rad(A)=nil(A)

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I've been having trouble approaching this problem: Let A be a ring such that for every ideal I not contained in Nil(A), there exists a non zero idempotent in I (element e so that e^(2)=e). Prove then that Rad(A)=Nil(A), where Rad(A) is the Jacobson radical.

I know that $Nil(A)\subset Rad(A)$ is a given, because I'm in commutative algebra and we work with commutative rings with unity, but to show that $Rad(A)\subset Nil(A)$ I'm a bit lost. If Rad(A) is not contained in Nil(A), then there is an idempotent in Rad(A), and there must also exist some x in Rad(A) so that $x^n \neq 0$ for all naturals, but I don't know what to do with those elements. I know that Nil(A) is characterised by being the intersection of all prime ideals and Rad(A) by being the set of elements x so that 1-xy is invertible for all y in A. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\text{Rad}(A)\not\subset \text{Nil}(A)$. By hypothesis, there is some non-zero idempotent $x\in \text{Rad}(A) $. As you have pointed out, we have that $1-x$ is a unit in $A$. But $x(1-x)=x-x^2=0$, so $1-x$ is a zero divisor (because $x\neq 0$). But a unit cannot be a zero divisor, so we get a contradiction and hence $\text{Rad}(A)\subset \text{Nil}(A)$.

$\textbf{Note:}$ notice that this argument shows that, whatever the ring, the Jacobson radical cannot contain non-zero idempotents.